# R using ellipsis to add different variables

Tags: r, ellipsis

I am using ellipsis (three dots) in R and wants to know if its possible to add different variables using the same function. For e.g

```
    funct_add <-function(...)

    {    
    Function Body    
    }
```

> `funct_add(3,4,5)` Should return 12
>
> `funct_add(3,4,5,6)` Should return 18

Any help on the body of the function would be great.

Answer (score 0):

```
add1 <-function(...) sum(...)   
add2 <-function(...) Reduce(f = "+", list(...))
add1(3,4,5)
add2(3,4,5)
```

Comment: thanks. it worked...but i am unable to understand the logic behind

Comment: Is sum(...) an inbuilt function? What does the reduce function do? If I want to multiply all the variable arguments then what would be the code? I am at a loss :)